# Passing a SAFEARRAY from C# to COM

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

I use 3rd party COM to find faces in a picture. One of the methods has the following signature, from SDK:

```
long FindMultipleFaces(
  IUnknown* pIDibImage,
  VARIANTARG* FacePositionArray
);
```

> Parameters: pIDibImage[in] - The image
>   to search.
>
> FacePositionArray[out]- The array of
>   FacePosition2 objects into which face 
>   information is placed. This array is
>   in a safe array (VARIANT) of type
>   VT_UNKNOWN.  The size of the array
>   dictates the maximum number of faces
>   for which to search.

which translates into the following C# method signature (from metadata):

```
int FindMultipleFaces(object pIDibImage, ref object pIFacePositions);
```

Being optimistic I call it the following way but get an exception that the memory is corrupt. The exception is thrown only when a face is present in the image.

```
FacePosition2[] facePositions = new FacePosition2[10];
object positions = facePositions;
int faceCount = FaceLocator.FindMultipleFaces(dibImage, ref positions);
```

What's the right way to pass SAFEARRAY to unmanaged code?

Comment: Found the cause of the problem: the array has to be manually initialized because FacePosition2 is not a struct. Ouch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, it seems it only needed from me to initialize the array because FacePosition2 was not a struct but class and it was not initialized automatically as I though it would. This piece was missing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < facePositions.Length; i++)
{
  facePositions[i] = new FacePosition2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's something like you initialize an array using `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem` and then use `Marshal.Copy` to copy it to unmanaged memory and the pass an `IntPtr` pointing to the array into the COM method.

In general, look at the `Marshal` class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx

Comment: Oops, it seems it only needed from me to initialize the array because FacePosition2 was not a struct but class and it was not initialized automatically as I though it would. 

                FacePosition2[] facePositions = new FacePosition2[10];
                for (var i = 0; i < facePositions.Length; i++)
                {
                    facePositions[i] = new FacePosition2();
                }

Answer (score 0):

There are more sophisticated method, but opinion is more correct:
change this signature Interop, so, he looks like taking an array.

[Accessing a SafeArray Result from a COM Call in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/marshallingarrayofstructs.aspx)

[Default Marshaling for Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6(VS.80).aspx)

[Correcting Common Interop Assembly Problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289520(VS.71).aspx#vbtchtroubleshootingnetinteroperabilityanchor3)